# Display or hide fragment menu

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I'm trying to create an activity with three different fragments as menus.

The user should see only the fragment he needs to according to some data the activity has.

This is my main XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/MainScreenLayout"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ibuy.ibuy.MainScreen">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="ibuy.ibuy.MainScreen">

        .
        .
        .

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:name="Menus.ManagerMainMenu"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:alpha="255"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:name="Menus.MainConnectedMenu"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:alpha="255"/>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer3"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:name="Menus.MainDisConnectedMenu"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            android:alpha="255"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my main Java file:

```
public class MainScreen extends ActionBarActivity implements ManagerMainMenu.NavigationDrawerCallbacks,MainConnectedMenu.NavigationDrawerCallbacks,MainDisConnectedMenu.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    .
    .
    .
    private ManagerMainMenu mnMenu = new ManagerMainMenu();
    private MainConnectedMenu conMenu = new MainConnectedMenu();
    private MainDisConnectedMenu disMenu = new MainDisConnectedMenu();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        .
        .
        .

        mnMenu = (ManagerMainMenu) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer1);

        mnMenu.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer1, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        conMenu = (MainConnectedMenu) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer2);

        conMenu.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer2, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        disMenu = (MainDisConnectedMenu) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer3);

        disMenu.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer3, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (storeID > 0) {
            ft.show(mnMenu);
            ft.hide(conMenu);
            ft.hide(disMenu);
        } else if (userID > 0) {
            ft.hide(mnMenu);
            ft.show(conMenu);
            ft.hide(disMenu);
        } else {
            ft.hide(mnMenu);
            ft.hide(conMenu);
            ft.show(disMenu);
        }
        ft.commit();
    }

    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.MainScreenLayout, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        .
        .
        .

    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

The three fragments are the same part of their array of list of items.

This is one on the fragments Java file:

```
public class ManagerMainMenu extends Fragment {

    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;
    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    public ManagerMainMenu() {    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                selectItem(position);
            }
        });
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{"Store Rank", "Store Details", "Sales", "Add Item",
                        "Update Store Details", "Personal Details", "LogOut"}));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
        return mDrawerListView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

I tried using setMenuVisibility() and setUserVisibleHint() but it had no influence. Afterwards I tried using FragmentTransaction with show and hide and it also did nothing.

How can I hide two of the fragments and display the third?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

if (storeID > 0) {
    ft.show(mnMenu);
    ft.hide(conMenu);
    ft.hide(disMenu);
} else if (userID > 0) {
        ...
}
```

And so on..